# Symfony2 using Query builder to load a specific ManyToMany object

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, query-builder

My product can have many categories. In one part of the object however, I need to get a specific Category. So instead of getting all the categories and then in a for loop search for specific one, I need to get only this specific category. For that I am using query builder.

```
public function findProduct($id) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->addSelect(array('p', 'cat'))  // many to many table
        ->addSelect(array('p', 'category')) // the category entity
        ->leftJoin('p.category', 'cat')
        ->leftJoin('cat.category', 'category')
        ->andWhere("category.id = 15") // error here
        ->SetParameter('id', $id);


    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

With this query I am easily able to do $`product->getCategory[0]`([] since array) and get only the category that I need(in this example category with id=15)

**THE PROBLEM:**

However if the product doesnt have a category with a specific id.. It returns whole product null..

So If i do:

```
 $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findProduct($id); = null
```

But instead it should be like this:

```
 $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findProduct($id); = object

$product->getCategory() = null
```

How can I make this work in query builder? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Instead of constraining your whole query (which is what that does) just constrain the join).

> leftJoin('cat.category', 'category', 'WITH', 'category.id = 15')

This way you should get your product always & category only if id == 15.